# Update Errors on Ubuntu- I get this message

Tags: 12.04, apt

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shakaran/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shakaran/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you added an PPA (repository that is not supported by Cannonical), and the PPA is unreachable. To fix, simply remove the PPA: edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and remove this link from the file. You will need root (sudo) to save after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You have added PPAs that are dead, or unreachable for some clause, happened to me before too, it is not a big deal, nothing to be afraid of, you can fix this bu removing the PPAs from your software sources or use :

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPANAME
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPANAME
sudo apt-get update
```

Now i left PPANAME beclause i dont know the exact name of the PPAs, anyone edit me freely